# OpenID and OAuth: successor of lightopenid?

Tags: php, oauth, openid, openid-connect, lightopenid

Oauth 2.0 seems to be the best-supported tool for external authentication. However, after many, many hours of searching the web I find that there are no easy ways to get started with this when using PHP. Or perhaps (and hopefully) I am just not searching in the right way.

Here is what I am looking for:

- A way to implement external authentication on my website.
- I am NOT looking for any external resources (so I don't need photos or posts or tweets or anything from the external website - I only want to use it to offer users a way to register/log in without creating yet another password).
- Support for multiple websites without me going over the complex documentation for each of those sites. Preferably the most popular sites like Google, Facebook, and Yahoo are supported.
- There are two characteristics that I value over pretty much anything else: simplicity (the fewer files, the fewer dependencies, and the easier to implement, the better) and reliability (preferably a popular repository, used by many, not from some obscure site that is downloaded as a zipfile).

I *think* [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) is what I need, but the OpenID website lists complex OpenID Server solutions on its website, rather than clients, under PHP software (see [recommended libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)). In earlier times [LightOpenID](https://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/) provided pretty much what I needed. But this is now outdated. Is there a LightOpenID successor?

Answer (score 0):

Though there's no direct followup of LightOpenID supporting OpenID Connect, there's a number of PHP implementations for OpenID Connect out there, one that seems to be doing well on Github is: https://github.com/ivan-novakov/php-openid-connect-client but there are more according to Google and it is certainly not impossible to roll your own if you restrict yourself to the Basic Client Profile: http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/07/how-simple-is-openid-connect-basic.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repository that provides lightweight Google-only authentication: https://github.com/PenguinProtocols/Basic-OpenID-Connect-Google

Very easy to set up and documentation is quite clear.